# Disable COD for other countries

Tags: magento-1.9, address, cash-on-delivery

I want to disable Cash on delivery(COD) for all the other countries other than one. for example, if I select India in the address field the COD should be enabled and if I select any other country it should get disabled. Kindly let me know how can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `System->Configuration->Payment Methods->Cash On Delivery Payments->Payment from Applicable Countries`.
Select `Specific Countries`

Then 
`Payment from Specific Countries` Select Only `India`
That's It.

Comment: @Akshay Vasu : is your problem is solved now?